# Graph APi: "(#3) Unknown method" error while trying to reply a private message

Tags: facebook-graph-api, fan-page, reply, private-messaging

I'm using the Facebook Graph API to reply a direct message.
I have published my message issuing an HTTP POST request to `/CONVERSATION_ID/messages` with a valid access token.
But I receive the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) Unknown method",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3
  }
}
```

The same test on the Graph API Explorer returned the same error.
Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

My Workplace (Facebook for business) GRAPH API application received a "(#3) Unknown method" error when it didn't have POST or DELETE permissions for the action it was attempting. Changing the integration/application permissions resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `/messages` to the API. Just call the API as `https://graph.facebook.com/{message_id}` to get the thread.

Comment: hello @NirajShah ,thanks for the answer. I have no problem for retrievng the thread, that work well. But i'm trying to send a message by calling the API as "/CONVERSATION_ID/messages" the thread.But it still don't work.